# HTML table new row added event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my web application, I'm creating an Invoice module.

Here in the view, I have added a text box to search the item and another text box to add Qty.

There is a `Add` button also, and the user clicks the button, I passed the item details to the table.

So there I want to do a calculation.

I want to know if is there an event to catch the new row added to the table to me to calculate the line amount.? Or if there is another way to do this easily.

These are my current code.

HTML View

```
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th width="40%"> Item </th>
       <th width="10%"> Measure By </th>
       <th width="10%"> Stock In Hand </th>
       <th width="10%"> Bill Qty </th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Type the Item Name or Number Here" class="form-control" id="itemSearchBox" />
         <input type="hidden" id="selectedItemID" />
         <input type="hidden" id="selectedItemName" />
         <input type="hidden" id="selectedItemRate" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="text" placeholder="0" disabled class="form-control" id="selectedItemMeasure" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="text" placeholder="0" disabled class="form-control" id="ItemAvaQty" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="text" placeholder="0" class="form-control" id="ItemBillQty" />
       </td>
       <td></td>
       <td>
         <button id="addItem" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {

  try {
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
      var customerID = document.getElementById("CustomerID").value == 0 ? 0 : document.getElementById("CustomerID").value;
      if (customerID == 0) {

        toastr.error('You need to select the customer First');
      } else {
        var newRow = $(
          '<tr id="tablerow' +
          counter +
          '" class ="invoiceSet"> ' +
          "<td>" +
          '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
          counter +
          "</strong></label>" +
          "</td>" +
          '<td width="40%">' +
          '<input type="text" value="' + $("#selectedItemName").val() + '" class="form-control ItemID" disabled data-id =' + $("#selectedItemID").val() + ' name="Item_Id[' +
          counter +
          ']" id="ItemId[' + counter + ']"  > ' +
          "</td>" +
          '<td width="10%">' +
          '<input type="text" class="form-control Qty" name="Qty[' +
          counter +
          ']" value="' + $("#ItemBillQty").val() + '" id="Qty[' + counter + ']"   data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
          "</td>" +
          '<td width="10%">' +
          '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
          counter +
          ']" value="' + $("#selectedItemMeasure").val() + '" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
          "</td>" +
          '<td width="20%">' +
          '<input type="text" class="form-control UnitPrice" name="Unit_Price[' +
          counter +
          ']" value="' + $("#selectedItemRate").val() + '" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
          "</td>" +
          '<td width="8%">' +
          '<input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control lineDisc" name="Line_Discount[' +
          counter +
          ']" value="0.00" id="Line_Discount[' + counter + ']"  data-Line_DiscountId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
          "</td>" +
          '<td width="20%">' +
          '<input type="text" class="form-control LineTotal" name="Line_Total[' +
          counter +
          ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
          "</td>" +
          "<td>" +
          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
          counter +
          ');">x</button>' +
          "</td>" +
          "</tr>"
        );

        newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");
        counter++;

        return false;
      }

    });
  } catch (e) {

  }

});
```

This is the calculation I want to do for each row added to the table

```
 $(document).on("change", ".Qty , .UnitPrice , .lineDisc ", function () {

   var element = $(this).closest("tr");
   var qty = element.find(".Qty").val();
   var unit_price = element.find(".UnitPrice").val();
   var line_disc = element.find(".lineDisc").val();
   var line_total = qty * unit_price;
   var total = line_total - (line_total * (line_disc / 100))

   element.find(".LineTotal").val(parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));

   calculate_total(); //call function

 })
```

@updated
So far I Did this, I created a function and,
after the  `newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");` section I call the function with the counter and then did the math.

```
 newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");
 lineTotalCal(counter);
 counter++;
```

function

```
function lineTotalCal(counter) {
  var qty = document.getElementById('Qty[' + counter + ']').value;
  var unit_price = document.getElementById('UnitPrice[' + counter + ']').value;
  var line_disc = document.getElementById('Line_Discount[' + counter + ']').value == 0 ? 0 : document.getElementById('Line_Discount[' + counter + ']').value;
  var line_total = qty * unit_price;
  var total = line_total - (line_total * (line_disc / 100))
  var LineMasterTotal = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
  document.getElementById('LineTotal[' + counter + ']').value = LineMasterTotal;
  calculate_total(); //call function
}
```

Comment: How is this C# related?